# illegal offset using dynamic variable

Tags: php, arrays

I dont unserstand why do i get such errors:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in
>   .../index.php on line 10 USD 1.4141
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in
>   .../index.php on line 10 JPY 118.56

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("eurofxref-daily.xml");
$array=array();
foreach ($xml->children() as $cubeMain) {
    foreach ($cubeMain->children() as $cubeTime) {
        echo "Time: " . $cubeTime['time'];
        foreach ($cubeTime->children() as $cubeCurr) {
            $currency=$cubeCurr['currency'];
            $rate=$cubeCurr['rate'];
            $array = array($currency => $rate);
            echo $currency . "&nbsp;" . $rate . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `$array = array((string)$currency => $rate);`.

SimpleXML returns objects, not strings - and while they have proper `__toString` methods, PHP doesn't use them when these objects are used as an array index.

Comment: Ty, but how to echo later the keys with values?

Comment: What do you mean? To `echo` them using the object itself is fine since they are properly converted to a string when used in a string context. Your code even does that...

Comment: My target is: 1) Get all the currencies with rate into an array 2) Print out Currency and rate from array.

Comment: @Marko `foreach($array as $currency => $rate) echo "$currency: $rate\n";`